# Read facebook feed sorted by updated_time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to read feed from facebook based on updated time through API?

I tried "since" and "until" but both are reading the data based on created time.

FQL will be deprecated and i dont know how to sort it by updated_time with graph api call.

Anyone else found any solution or any other solution that i could use for updates?

Thanks

Comment: BTW keep in mind that if your app uses read_stream permission and is not for windows phone or any other platform where FB is not presented, your app WILL NOT be approved by submission team. This mistake cost us the whole app to be changed right before release. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

Comment: Look into _real-time updates_.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, i have looked into it, and i am implementing it as we speak. Seems like it is the way to go for now, unless facebook decides to implement custom sort parameter in the graph api feed call, update_time instead of default create time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API search using since updated\_time parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818119/facebook-graph-api-search-using-since-updated-time-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

You currently cannot apply a custom sort parameter in the Graph API. So, it's not possible to sort by `updated_time`. Furthermore, the `read_stream` permission will be phased out on April 30th 2015.

If you have a v2.0 app, you can use FQL until August 7th 2016. Maybe this would be a solution as well and wait for potential changes in the Graph API.

Comment: Read all and sort by `updated_time` in your application.

Comment: Tobi, this is unacceptable. You cant read thousands of messages and sort them, because of paging you dont know how deep you need to go, one message can be updated from a year ago because a comment was added..

Comment: I have already rewritten my application to use GRAPH api only, with FQL this was easy to solve. With graph api, i dont see the options to do the same as with FQL. Is there any alternative to read updates on your page?

Comment: You can always file a bug with Facebook and let them describe a solution if you want an official statement. I doubt that it's currently possible without reading "all" posts and sort them within the application.

Comment: Thanks Tobi for all the answers, i am looking for a different solution because reading all messages is not an option for any application.

Comment: I can only repeat myself, and that's boring